# How to Discard None Values in a Function Arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a function `df()` that does some operations to a input *args:

```
def df(*args):
    for arg in args:
        # do some computation
```

And I have this three variables that are going to be the arguments of `df()`:

```
a = 1234
b = 4321
c = None
```

Is there any way I can 'discard' this nonetype value on the function call?

I know I could add a condition inside the function but in my case I have many more functions that are also going to receive this values, so is there any way of 'discard' some kind of parameters in a function call?

Comment: Maybe you can make a decorator that filters out `None` values.

Comment: Would it be possible to show the relationship between this function and the "many more functions"? Whether they are called inside of or outside of this function will affect answers to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A decorator that filters out None from your function arguments:

```py
def omit_none(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        args = [arg for arg in args if arg is not None]
        return f(*args)
    return wrapper
```

then use it as

```py
@omit_none
def df(*args):
    for arg in args:
        # do some computation
```

That's assuming you don't plan to use keyword arguments with the affected functions.

---

> In case I have this other function bar(user, *args) and I need to just use the decorator on args

OK. Here is a more adaptable version:

```py
def omit_none_from(index):
    def omit_none_from(func):
        def wrapper(*args):
            args = list(args[:index]) + [arg for arg in args[index:] if arg is not None]
            return func(*args)
        return wrapper
    return omit_none_from
```

which you use as:

```py
@omit_none_from(1)
def bar(user, *args):
    ...
```

This will filter out None from argument 1 onwards, so it will leave the first argument, `user` untouched.

Comment: Awesome! In case I have this other function `bar(user, *args)` and I need to just use the decorator on `args`, I would have to select `args[1]` inside `omit_one`, wouldn't I?

Comment: If you use case is different for the different functions, then a simple decorator isn't going to cover it. You could write a second decorator that works differently, or a decorator with an extra parameter describing which argument to start the filter at.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was again what a was looking for.

Comment: I have one more question, what if *args are all None? It won't pase nothing to the function and it will raise a TypeError, what would you do to solve this?

Comment: If all args are None it will call your function passing no arguments. What your function does with that is up to you.